# How does RxJS catch errors under the hood?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've used rxjs in Angular, and I'm familiar with the use of the `catchError` operator in the `pipe` flow, especially for HttpClient (XHR) calls

My question is how does the `catchError` operation work? How is it catching the error under the hood?

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html

```
import { throwError, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
//emit error
const source = throwError('This is an error!');
//gracefully handle error, returning observable with error message
const example = source.pipe(catchError(val => of(`I caught: ${val}`)));
//output: 'I caught: This is an error'
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

**Update:**

Using the details from the Accepted Answer, I tested it out with the following in a StackBlitz TypeScript project. Good example to see the try/catch and subscriber.error being used:

```
import { throwError, of, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const exampleOne$ = new Observable(subscriber => {
  throw new Error('thrown');
});

exampleOne$.pipe(
  catchError(val => of(`Exmaple One ${val}`))
).subscribe(console.log); // Exmaple One Error: thrown

const exampleTwo$ = new Observable(subscriber => {
  try {
    throw new Error('native error')
  }
  catch (e) {
    subscriber.error(e);
  }
});

exampleTwo$.pipe(
  catchError(val => of(`Example Two ${val}`)) 
).subscribe(console.log); // Example Two Error: thrown
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `catchError` operator doesn't directly catch errors in the same way that exceptions are caught using a `try`/`catch` statement.

Internally, it subscribes to the source observable to which it is applied and mirrors the source's `next` and `complete` notifications - that is, those notifications flow through the operator unchanged.

However, if the operator receives an `error` notification, it passes the error to the supplied callback, giving the caller of the operator the opportunity to handle the error.

An `error` notification can be effected within an observable implementation by calling the subscriber's `error` method, like this:

```js
const source = new Observable<string>(subscriber => {
  subscriber.error(new Error'Kaboom!'));
});
```

Here, no exception is thrown and no `try`/`catch` is required. The error is passed to the subscriber - the `catchError` operator subscribes to the source, so [it's the subscriber](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.3.3/src/internal/operators/catchError.ts#L103-L130) - via its `error` method.

That's how the `throwError` function used in the question [is implemented](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.3.3/src/internal/observable/throwError.ts#L69-L75).

An `error` notification can also be effected by throwing an exception, like this:

```js
const source = new Observable<string>(subscriber => {
  throw new Error('Kaboom!');
});
```

Here, the `try`/`catch` statement in the [implementation of `Observable.subscribe`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.3.3/src/internal/Observable.ts#L222-L236) will catch the exception and will pass an error notification to the subscriber by calling the subscriber's `error` method.

The catching of thrown exceptions is the responsibility of the `Observable` and operator implementations.

Wherever user-specified functions are passed - for example, in operators like `map` - calls made to those functions are [wrapped in a `try`/`catch` statements](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.3.3/src/internal/operators/map.ts#L80-L85) and any caught exceptions are passed to the subscriber as `error` notifications via the subscriber's `error` method.